# The phpMyAdmin server not showing the port

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, port

When I'm on phpMyAdmin my server has no port. It says "Server:localhost" then no port. What can I do to arrange that.[image]

Comment: WHen you use `localhost` it connects using a Unix-domain socket, not a network port.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: ok thank you, I get it. it's normal then